# code working, but not as intended. Attempting to print the days of each month, based on input -- to include a leap year. Type Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I know that this question has been asked before, but my code was working for a `February (02) input`, but now is not. I am getting a `Type Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting` My code was executing without any errors but was not printing any of the days out. Any help is appreciated as I am still learning.

```
def isLeapyear(year):
  return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 == 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def calcDays():
    year = input('Please enter the year in XXXX format ')
    month = input('Please enter the month in XX format ')

    if month  == ('01', '03', '05', '07', '08', '10', '12'):
        print (31)

    elif month  == ('04', '06', '09', '11'):
        print (30)

    elif month == '02' and isLeapyear(year) == True:
        print (29)

    elif month == '02' and isLeapyear(year) == False:
        print (28)

calcDays()
```

Comment: @Evorage that is not a proper answer. The problem is that he wants to `%` the string, not int

Comment: Why to re-invent the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module ?

Comment: For future reference if you want to check whether a set of exact string inputs match one of the strings in a tuple (or a list), you can do something like e.g. `if month in ('01', '03', '05', '07', '08', '10', '12')`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this one you have to change year into int which is a str before taking mode and i also changed the condition for leapyear

```
def isLeapyear(year):
    return ((int(year) % 4 == 0) and (int(year) % 100 != 0)) or (int(year) % 400 == 0)


def calcDays():
    year = input('Please enter the year in XXXX format ')
    month = input('Please enter the month in XX format ')

    if month == '01' or month == '03' or month == '05' or month == '07' or month == '08' or month == '10' or month == '12':
        print(31)

    elif month == '04' or month == '06' or month == '09' or month == '11':
        print(30)

    elif month == '02' and isLeapyear(year) == True:
        print(29)

    elif month == '02' and isLeapyear(year) == False:
        print(28)


calcDays()
```

Comment: Hey, it's not possible to compare the variable like that is it? You have to use `month in (something)` right? or `month == '01' or month == '02' or ...`

Comment: Thanks! I had tried using 'or' but not the proper way so it was giving me an error. I am just noticing something, when I input a leap year, some leap years result accurately, for example, the year 2000...But others, like the current year, 2020, does not? I have checked, but I am assuming there has to be an issue with the calculation in isLeapyear(), correct?

Comment: You also want `year` as an `int` for those modulus to work...

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
Just posting that if you want to compute the leap year in python correctly and don't want to use a calendar class, use:

```
def IsLeapYear(year):
    if (year % 400 == 0)
        return True

    if (year % 100 == 0)
        return False

    if (year % 4 == 0)
        return True

    return False
```

or more optimized:

```
def GregorianIsLeapYear(y):
    if ((y % 4) != 0)
        return False
    if ((y % 100) != 0)
        return True
    return (y % 400) == 0
```